# How to speed up video processing in Python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I've been working on a video processing algorithm in MATLAB and want to transfer it into Python so that I can eventually move it to a Raspberry Pi.

Obviously, certain functions in MATLAB - like 'imfilter', was impossible to replicate in Python, so I ended up writing some codes. The code so far is as 
follows:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    ker = np.array((...))              # 9 x 9 array - to be used as a kernel
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(3, 320)
    cap.set(4, 240)
    while(1):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # the following lines are for recreating MATLAB imfilter in Python
        x_start = 0
        y_start = 0
        x_lim = len(gray[:,1]) - len(ker)
        y_lim = len(gray[1,:]) - len(ker)
        x = x_start
        y = y_start
        imfil = np.zeros([len(gray[:,1]), len(gray[1,:])])

        for x in range(x_start,x_lim):
             for y in range(y_start,y_lim):
                  z = ker * gray[x:x+len(ker),y:y+len(ker)]
                  sum_z = sum(sum(z))
                  imfil[x+1,y+1] = sum_z
                  y = y + 1

    cv2.imshow('original', gray)
    cv2.imshow('orientation', imfil)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

The end result is similar enough to what I get in MATLAB, but the problem is that processing speed is too slow. Is there any place that I can modify for improvement in running speed?

P.S. I've tried using scipy.ndimage.correlate and cv2.filter2D as an alternative, but the results given is completely different to MATLAB version. Can anyone help me understand why? :s

Many thanks in advance, and glad to finally officially join stack community. ^^;;

Comment: `imfilter` defaults to using correlation, which `cv2.filter2D` is the OpenCV equivalent.  What do you mean that the "results" are completely different?  Can you provide a sample input image, sample kernel, and what the outputs look like for both MATLAB and OpenCV?  It's impossible to determine what's going on without what you've done for both environments in full.  You don't have enough reputation to upload photos, so link us to a public sharing website where we have access.

Comment: BTW, I've modified your tags to ensure your question has more exposure.  You didn't include Python or OpenCV or MATLAB in your tags, so a lot of people may have missed your question in their news feeds.

Comment: also check out scikit-image. It provides a filter module: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.html

Comment: Thanks @P.R. I've checked out the scikit-image, and found something that fitted in.

Comment: I am glad it worked. If you found a solution that works for you, feel free to post an answer to your own question. In this way others with the same question profit as well.